# Ошибка: VERR ACCESS DENIED в virtual box при установке

Tags: windows, virtualbox, usb, boot

Скачал последнюю версию Virtual BOX и Virtual USB BOOT. Попытался установить win10(64) с флешки на виртуальную машину. Сам файл .vdmk создался, но при запуске пишет:

> VERR ACCESS DENIED.

Флешка fat32. Менял настройки машины, не помогало.

Какие варианты еще есть?

Comment: Попробуйте - https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=38914#p175089